# Order and number of tags

Tags: discussion, tagging, retagging

I won recently the privilege of retag questions.

It is important to put tags in some order in a specific question? I think that the leftmost tag is the most important tag because this tag appear on "title" of web explorer.

How many tags we must put in a question? I retag(ed) this question [Evaluating: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi} e^x\cos(nx)\space dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158836/evaluating-lim-n-to-infty-int-0-pi-ex-cosnx-space-dx) because it have many tags /some with very little in common with real question) like integration, integral, real-analysis etc..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The order of the tags is determined automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87508/are-the-tags-shown-in-a-particular-order), ranked from highest to lowest "popularity" (which, I would guess, is probably just the number of questions already asked in that tag).

If you're not positive which tags apply to a question, I'd err (*slightly*) on the side of more tags than fewer; but there's a built-in minimum of 1 tag and maximum of 5 tags anyway, so you don't have that many options when it comes to how many tags to put on a question.